# Is it possible to select the class which appears for the first time?

Tags: css

Suppose we have this:

```css
<div class="a">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="b">3</div>
      </div>  
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="b">4</div>
    </div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div class="b">6</div>     
</div>
```

What we don't know: we dont't know how many class `b` exists(but at least one),neither do we know their concrete locations in the code.

What we know: Class `b` must exists in class `a`(`a` is parent element)

The problem is: how to select the class `b` which appears for the first time ? Take this code for example,the class `b` which has `3` inside must be selected.

Comment: Do you mean you need the first tag for a class? you can do like getElementsByClassName("b"); returns array just select[0]

Comment: Not possible with css only, switch to js.

Comment: As skobaljic said, currently it's not possibile with css only. You could use ```:nth-child(1 of .b)```, but so far it's supported by Safari only: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-nth-child-of

Answer (score 0):

with `javascript`

`document.querySelector('.b')` it will select only one class with first occurrence

it will select

```
<div>
   <div class="b">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If with pure css(without js),could it be possible to do that?

Comment: yes you can use
 .b:nth-child(1) {
  background: blue;
} 
supported browsers https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anth-child()

Comment: can you explain more  it selects 3 and 4 and create a jsfiddle for it

Comment: @NaveenKashyap It doesn't work.It will select those who are the first child of some parent element.In this code,it will select 3 and 4.But what we want is only 3.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a working example for you, where you can pass the **number** for which you want to get the **first occurrence** of the `div` which has `class b`. You only need to pass `numToSelect = num`, here `num` can be any number you want to search.

**Checkout below example:**

```js
var numToSelect = 3;

var filter   = Array.prototype.filter,
    div = document.querySelectorAll('.b'),
    filtered = filter.call( div, ( node ) => node.innerText == numToSelect)[0];
    
console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="b">3</div>
      </div>  
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="b">4</div>
    </div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div class="b">6</div>     
</div>
```